# Looking for a program that can redirect all Hard drive "Write" commands to second hard drive

Tags: hard-disk, disk-image

Essentially I am looking for a tool that can take a hard drive (in this case the OS Drive), and Redirect it to a clone drive on a Ramdisk. So when I restart the PC everything is reset.

Is there anything out there like this?

Having to copy everything from the base HDD to the Ramdisk every time would be very slow, so I am hoping that there' a program that can Intercept file access copy the file and stick it on the Ramdisk. (would make access times slightly longer but shouldn't be a noticeable amount unless the accessed files are very large).

One of the uses for this, is a public PC. That way if someone fills it with virus's, It can easily be reset just by turning it off and on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is software to accomplish what you want called [Reboot Restore Rx](http://www.horizondatasys.com/en/products_and_solutions.aspx?ProductId=18#Features).

Features include:

- Restore on Reboot
- Reset to Baseline on PC Start Up or Hard Reset
- One-Click Instant Updates
- VMWare Support
- Protects the MBR
- Works below Windows
- Mini OS Access
- Restore from unbootable Windows

Here is an [article](http://www.howtogeek.com/166205/how-to-easily-reset-a-computer-back-to-a-clean-state-each-time-it-boots/) you might want to read, as well.